# PHP read text file ignore specific tab

Tags: php

I have log file data(.txt) [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k72gi3exvluoa1n/reject_new.txt?dl=0)

As you can see on log file that has `Date` and `Time` content.

And now I have PHP function to get the data from log file.

```
$fromDateTime = new DateTime('Wed, Sep 19  2018 08:00:00');
$toDateTime = new DateTime('Wed, Sep 19  2018 19:59:00');
$file = file_get_contents('Reject.txt');
$lines = explode("\n", $file);

// counter
$rowsintimespan = 0;
// keys should correspond to columns
$keys = [
    'Date',
    'Time',
    'Battery level',
    'Piezo sound level',
    'Left (Channel 3) light intensity',
    'Right (Channel 1) light intensity'
];

$values = array_fill(0, count($keys), 0);
$values = array_combine($keys, $values);

// Do Line-By-Line starting by Line 16 (Array Index 15)
for ($i = 11; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    // if the file is "Tue, Sep 18<tab>2018<tab>23:59:53<tab>"
    $dateobj = DateTime::createFromFormat("???,?M?d??Y?H:i:s+", $lines[$i]);

    // check if date is in your Timespan
    if ($dateobj < $toDateTime && $dateobj > $fromDateTime) {
        $rowsintimespan++; // count if in timespan

        // get line elements
        $lineContent = explode("\t", $lines[$i]);

        // loop through line elements and count them
        $x = 0;
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($keys); $j++) {
            if (!isset($lineContent[$j])) {
                continue;
            }

            // remember position of last not empty column
            if (trim($lineContent[$j]) != '') {
                $x = $j;
            }
        }

        if ($x > 0) {
            $values[$keys[$x]]++;
        }
    }
}

// Debug-Output
echo $rowsintimespan;

// Output every column
echo '<pre>';
print_r($values);
```

And now I don't want `Date` and `Time` including on counting. So I try to remove both, but the result of count is not in the correct `keys`.

My question, is it possible to ignore both keys then the counting is keep correct?

[image]

Above image, I try to removed `Date` and `Time`.
The correct one should be, `Battery level = 2` and `Piezo sound level = 2`.

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. Are you trying to get only the values between a certain timeframe,is that it?

Comment: You may find some parts of the code interesting, still, not enough for an answer, as I don't fully understand your question - https://gist.github.com/x011/a764ee4dab50158725a15180b9c948fa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should subtract the number of columns:
`$values[$keys[$x]]++;` → `$values[$keys[$x - 2]]++;`

Here is an updated code snippet:

```
<?php
$fromDateTime = new DateTime('Tue, Nov 13  2018 08:00:00');
$toDateTime = new DateTime('Tue, Nov 13  2018 19:59:00');
$file = file_get_contents('reject_new.txt');
$lines = explode("\n", $file);

const IGNORE_COLS = 2;  // +++ Introduced const for number of columns to skip

// counter
$rowsintimespan = 0;
// keys should correspond to columns
$keys = [
    // 'Date',         // +++ 
    // 'Time',         // +++ 
    'Battery level',
    'Piezo sound level',
    'Left (Channel 3) light intensity',
    'Right (Channel 1) light intensity'
];

$values = array_fill(0, count($keys), 0);
$values = array_combine($keys, $values);

// Do Line-By-Line starting by Line 12 (Array Index 11)
for ($i = 11; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    // if the file is "Tue, Sep 18  2018<tab>23:59:53<tab>"
    $dateobj = DateTime::createFromFormat("???,?M?d??Y?H:i:s+", $lines[$i]);

    // check if date is in your Timespan
    if ($dateobj < $toDateTime && $dateobj > $fromDateTime) {
        $rowsintimespan++; // count if in timespan

        // get line elements
        $lineContent = explode("\t", $lines[$i]);

        // loop through line elements and count them
        for ($j = IGNORE_COLS; $j < count($keys); $j++) {
            if (!isset($lineContent[$j])) {
                continue;
            }

            if (trim($lineContent[$j]) != '') {
                $values[$keys[$j - IGNORE_COLS]]++;   // −−− Remove redundant $x var
            }
        }
    }
}

// Debug-Output
echo $rowsintimespan . PHP_EOL;

// Output every column
echo '<pre>' . PHP_EOL;
print_r($values);
```